# Sending array to API and getting empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I wrote a function in angularjs, that send the array to API. (I'm using asp.net).

```
function getDimensionTagsByIds(tagIds) {

        return msApi.resolve('app.entities.dimensions-tags-search@query', {tagsId: tagIds});
    }
```

this is the function in the API that receives this request:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("tags-search")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IQueryable<SimpleDimensionViewModel>> SearchTags([FromUri] List<int> tagIds)
    {
        return (await _mediator.SendAsync(new ProjectedQuery<DimensionTag, SimpleDimensionViewModel>())).Where(dt => tagIds.Contains((int)dt.TagId));
    }
```

when I debug my code I see that the tagIds get all the time empty List.
I tried to change the parameter to array, but its still doesn't work. 
what I'm doing wrong?

thanks for the help!

Comment: You are sending object with "tagsId" property. Plural tagS and singular Id. And your parameter is singular - tag and plural IdS

Comment: no, tagsid is an array of string, I tried to change the type of the list to be  list<string> but it still, refuse to work

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear - I meant that you have different names there. tagsid vs tagids. If you have different types on top of it - the app should throw the conversion exception. To debug it you could change the list to have strings instead of ints - just for testing

Comment: Thanks! now its working!

Comment: No worries. I`ll post this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a simple typo:

Your angular is sending property tag**s**Id And your backend is waiting for tagId**s**